# Bootstrap html table with wide bottom column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I need to do table like this (on picture).

But it is important to be a bootstrap table, so what you see on picture can have only 3 table rows, not 6 because I want to use style

```
table class="table table-striped table-hover"
```

Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Why bootstrap table not grid?... (if you add 'bootstrap' all bootstrap pros can find your post ;) )

Comment: I have tried colspan rowspan combinations etc but nothing worked. I want boostrap because of table-hover functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The **colspan** and **rowspan** attribute should do the trick.

Try this code:

```
<div class="table-responsive" style='width:50%'>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Name</td>
            <td>Sex</td>
            <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Junmar Jose</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Weslie Andrea Lavita</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Name</td>
            <td>Sex</td>
            <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Junmar Jose</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Weslie Andrea Lavita</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image]

This is just a dummy data to show how the columns and rows are separated.

Hope this helps! Goodluck!

Comment: If you split those cells into more table rows (tr) the "table-hover" effect doesn't work properly.

Comment: Can you explain how the hover is divided? @mojmir.novak

Comment: You can see that on your picture ... when you hover mouse over first "row" the "column" Junmar Jose is not selected together with whole row (the column is white, should be gray).
And the same column on second row should be white if mouse is not on it.